# Is a pushout of a closed immersion $f$ again a closed immersion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Assume
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
X&\xrightarrow{f}& Y\\
\downarrow && \downarrow\\
Z&\xrightarrow{f'}& W
\end{eqnarray}
$$
is a pushout in the category of schemes (and in particular $W$ is a scheme).

> Is $f'$ a closed (resp. open) immersion, if $f$ is a closed (resp. open) immersion?

This is true if you replace ''scheme'' by ''topological space'' and ''immersion'' just by ''map'' or ''embedding''.

Comment: This seems relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29306/why-is-the-fibered-coproduct-of-affine-schemes-not-affine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is quite hard to answer, since pushouts in the category of schemes don't exist in general, even along closed immersions. And it is hard to determine whether some morphism is a closed immersion when you just know a universal property. But have a look at "Conducteur, Descent et Pincement" by Daniel Ferrand and "Gluing Schemes and a Scheme Without Closed Points" by Karl Schwede, these papers are available online. Karl Schwede proves the following: If $X,Y,Z$ are affine, then $W$ exists and is affine, and in fact $f'$ is a closed immersion. This comes down to the observation that in the category of commutative rings $A \times_B C \to C$ is surjective when $A \to B$ is surjective. If $X,Y,Z$ are general schemes, $f : X \to Y$ *and* $X \to Z$ are closed immersions, when $W$ exists and $f'$ is a closed immersion. For more general results, see Ferrand's paper or [MO/64294](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64294).

Comment: Dear @Martin, thank you for the answer. Ok, suppose $f$ and the morphism from $X$ to $Z$ are both closed immersions and $W$ is not affine. Can't one pull the whole diagram back along an open affine subscheme $U\to W$ (where it is true according to your answer) and use that to be a closed immersion is a local property? To do so, the 'pulled back diagram' has to be a pushout as well and I don't know if that holds in schemes.

Comment: Yes this isn't clear a priori. We need to use a construction of the pushout. As I've explained, this is done in Karl Schwede's paper (we don't need that $W$ is affine).

Comment: Dear @Martin, is this clear to you a posteriori? I am interested in the situation that $f$ and the morphism from $X$ to $Z$ is a closed immersion but none of the schemes is necessarily affine. Do you think my pullback argument works? As I've said, I see no reason for the pullback of the diagram to $U$ to be a pushout, do you?

Comment: Yes the argument works. But one uses the (local) construction of pushouts.